# Generate sequence diagram using C#

Tags: c#, .net

Hello is there any tool/api available to generate a customize sequence diagram based on certain user input?

Comment: Coz we want to mass generate sequence diagram from an input file

Comment: @reggibyYEAH: _mass generation_ would be relevant enough to be added to the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to attack this would be to use Visio (if your licensing scheme is compatible):

Here is a codeplex project that is supposed to make this easier from .NET (I haven't used it):
http://visioautomation.codeplex.com/

Another way to do this would be to just write some [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) code. I think that there are a number of open source projects that might help you in this effort as well.

A really expensive (but really good) implementation is from [yWorks](http://yWorks.com) - it's [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html).  I've used it and it's extremely powerful.

Answer (score 0):

VS2010 provides such a [feature](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/11/20/visual-studio-2010-generating-sequence-diagrams-on-the-fly.aspx), you might need the premium or ultimate version. If you need a whole bunch, you might write a macro or even an extension to VS.

Comment: yeah, actually we have the ultimate version aleady but that one is generating based on the code right? we want something that will generate based on an input file and mass generate the sequence diagrams.

Comment: @reggieboyYeah you don't have any code yet? So don't use C# as input rather than as generator.

Comment: yeah thats what i want basically, mass generate sequence diagram from an input file of some sort.

Comment: Then it depends on the input format. You have to identify the actors /their classes and generate matching code for them (Class.cs). Then you need can take your sequence diagram description to script the VS component. The first step might be quite difficult depending on your "user input". The second steps seems to be straight forward.